# How to get pdf code using iText

Tags: java, itext

anyone have any idea how to use itext to get a output of a pdf codes, just like when you drag a pdf into Notepad++? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the PDF like any other textfile, e.g. with `FileReader/BufferedReader`. No need for iText here.